# Filtering list based on current users preferences in another list?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Ok, to set things up, I have two lists:

1. User preferences. Table stores a users ID (person picker), and a multiple-choice enabled site column, to indicate subjects the user is interested in.
2. Surveys table. This table stores various information, of which one is the same subjects site column referenced in the User preferences table.

What I'm trying to do, is display surveys in an empty data view. This is easy, I've got this.

However, I'd like the page to only show the surveys that the current user is interested in. So, where [CurrentUser] == user ID in the 'User Preferences' table, and from that - where site column choices in 'User Preferences' == site column choices in 'Surveys' table.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options I would try for this, both use jQuery.
One option is to use the client object model, the other SPServices.
The closest example I can give you in each is cascading drop downs.

[For the client object model, I would have a look at this post.](http://www.sharepointblog.cz/2012/01/cascaded-lookup-jquery-version-and.html)

[For SPServices look here](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns)

Either of these tools give you the ability to mess with the out of the box SharePoint components without having to release C# server components.

Comment: There is also my library called SharepointPlus that is, I think, easier to use than SPServices or the one coming from MS: http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/